# CSS spin animation doesn't start from center

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I try to use this CSS animation : http://tobiasahlin.com/spinkit/

But I would like that the circle begin with an height and width of 40px and not from 0.

So I try this : http://jsfiddle.net/Xroad/33ovfgeL/

The problem is that the circle doesn't start from his center. I need to keep a position of 100px from the top and left.

```
@keyframes sk-scaleout {
    0% {
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        -webkit-transform: scale(0);
        transform: scale(0);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
        transform: scale(1.0);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Then try `transform-origin: 50% 50%;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because the element is positioned with a `left` offset. Remove the below line from the rules and it should start from center.

```
left: 100px;
```

Setting [`transform-origin: 50% 50%` is not required because that is anyway the default setting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin).

```css
.spinner {
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 100%;
  animation: sk-scaleout 2.5s infinite ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes sk-scaleout {
  0% {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 540px;
    height: 540px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="spinner"></div>
```

---

If you want the circle to start at center-mid (that is vertical and horizontal center) then you can use the approach seen in the below snippet. Here the  actual spinner circle is produced by the pseudo-element which is positioned at horizontal and vertical mid of parent container by using positioning and translate transforms.

```css
.spinner {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.spinner:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 100%;
  animation: sk-scaleout 2.5s infinite ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes sk-scaleout {
  0% {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
  }
  100% {
    height: 540px;
    width: 540px;
    transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="spinner"></div>
```

---

If you for some reason want to retain the offset but still get it to start from **horizontal and vertical mid of container element** then just add the offset to the parent element like here:

```css
.spinner {
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid; /* just to illustrate where the element is on screen */
}
.spinner:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 100%;
  animation: sk-scaleout 2.5s infinite ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes sk-scaleout {
  0% {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
  }
  100% {
    height: 540px;
    width: 540px;
    transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="spinner"></div>
```

On the other hand if you want to retain the offset but get it to start from **horizontal and vertical mid of page** then use the below snippet:

```css
.spinner {
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.spinner:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: calc(50% - 100px);
  left: calc(50% - 100px);
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 100%;
  animation: sk-scaleout 2.5s infinite ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes sk-scaleout {
  0% {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
  }
  100% {
    height: 540px;
    width: 540px;
    transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="spinner"></div>
```

---

This works with just an offset and expanding from the center of the circle.

```css
.spinner {
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}
.spinner:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 100%;
  animation: sk-scaleout 2.5s infinite ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes sk-scaleout {
  0% {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
  }
  100% {
    height: 540px;
    width: 540px;
    transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="spinner"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I have the same problem :-/ and I need to put a left value cause I need to position the spin at a specific location

Comment: What do you mean @Xroad? I can see in the snippet window that it no longer starts at an offset. Are you looking to center it vertically also?

Comment: In your snippet I see the spinner to begin from the top of the window. In fact I need that the spinner be expanded from his center horizontally and vertically and be positioned at 100px from top and left

Comment: @Xroad: Refer to the second snippet that I have added to the answer. It has a solution for getting it to start from horizontal and vertical mid. I don't understand what you mean by *positioned at 100px* and then horizontal and vertical mid. If you position at 100px offset then it can no longer be from the middle unless we modify a lot of the properties.

Comment: Sorry, I think my explanations are not clear. I need to position my circle at 100px from the top and left of my window. I wish that my circle is expanding from its center but not from the center of my window. I wish that this circle begin with a height and a width of 40px not from 0px (like on the first link that I posted) and grows up to 540px.

Comment: @Xroad: I have fixed the starting height to be at 40px (instead of 0px) and either the third or fifth snippet should help you.

Comment: This is just perfect, thank you so much for your help

Comment: @Xroad: Wow, welcome. So which one was it finally? The third or fifth?

Comment: Finally the last snippet with the circle who begin from 40px and be positioned at 100px from top and left corner is all what I was looking for. Thank you !!